# Find the number of subspaces of 1-$\dim$ and 2-$\dim$ of a vector space with dimension $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the number of subspaces of 1-$\dim$ and 2-$\dim$ of a vector space with dimension $n$ over a field with $q$ elements.

I think the answers are:

For 1-$\dim$ we have $\dfrac{q^n-1}{q-1}$

And for the 2-$\dim$ we have $\dfrac{(q^n-1)(q^n-q)}{(q^2-1)(q^2-q)}$.

I figured these out using an example from the book. But I'm unclear as to the reasoning. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean over a finite field of $q$ elements?

Comment: yeah, sorry, that was supposed to say over a field with q elements.

Answer (score 1):

So $\,V\,$ is a vector space over a field $\,\Bbb F\,$ , with $\,|V|=q^n\,\,\,,\,|\Bbb F|=q\,$ .

Every $\,1-$dimensional subspace of $\,V\,$ is generated by one single non-zero element, say $\,0\neq v\in V\,$ , and this gives us $\,q^n-1\,$ elements. This number must be divided by $\,q-1\,$ since

$$Span\{v\}=Span\{kv\}\,\,,\,\,\forall\;k\in\Bbb F^*:=\Bbb F-\{0\}$$

and thus we get the number you wrote.

Try now to come up with a similar explanation for the number of $\,2-$dimensional subspaces, taking into account that

$$Span\{u,v\}=Span\{ku,mv\}\,\,,\,\forall\;k,m\in\Bbb F^*$$

for $\,u,v\in V\,$ linearly independent.